# How to change items in Electron Application menu at runtime?

Tags: electron

My electron app has an application menu which has "Open Recent" entries as submenu. The entries in this submenu give 10 most recently accessed documents. I populate this menu when the application starts and all works well. However in order to qualify for being "most recently" accessed documents, I've to refresh this list from time to time and not just at the application start. How can I achieve this?

There are two specific sub-questions to this

1. When can I update this? I was looking for some callback when the
   user clicks on the top level menu entry, where I could run the code
   to refresh this list. But I couldn't get that to work. The only
   callback the MenuItem has is 'click' and it doesn't seem to work if
   it has a submenu defined. A workaround for this is invoking
   setInterval and updating the menu entries at periodic times, say 1
   min. But if there's a callback where I can do this, I will prefer
   that.
2. How can I update this? I create a new Menu using `Menu.buildFromTemplate()` and then assign it to the `submenu` entry in the application menu hierarchy (I've saved the reference to the application menu when first time I created it). But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like `setMenu` is your only option. As for when to do it – for an "Open Recent" features, I would think you could do it when a document is opened (or after it has been closed): add the document to the menu template and call `setMenu` again.

---

This is from 2014 but it sounds like it is the defined behavior:

> [Modifying Menu object after setMenu can produce
>   unregistered/dangling accelerators #846](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/846)
>
> The proper way in atom-shell to update menu bar or application menu is
>   to call BrowserWindow.setMenu or app.setApplicationMenu after you
>   modified Menu object every time.
>
> This is because Menu actually acts as a model, and the native menu is
>   not created until you call setMenu, so if you change the model without
>   updating the native menu, bad things can happen. We use this design
>   because it perfectly represents the menu library used by Chromium, and
>   most menus are static.
>
> But I think we should find a way to prevent the crash and make it
>   clear in documents.

And:

> I'm closing this since we don't support changing menu object after
>   calling setMenu, the behavior is undefined if user does that.

Answer (score 1):

Menu.setApplicationMenu is what you are looking for. You can call it after you made changes to your menu.

```
const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
```

Comment: Can you give an example of "changing your menu"?  In the example you give, you are constructing a new menu from a template, not changing an existing menu.  The menu returned from `Menu.getApplicationMenu()` doesn't seem to have the data structure as passed to setApplicationMenu...